# How to implement a common background UIView for rest of other views?

Tags: uiview, background

In my iPad application I have a menu view in the left side and content view in the right side and a tab bar in the top which has 5 different tabs. Now I want to show different views in the menu view and content view when I change the tabs.

My question here is, I want to have a single instance for all those different views so whenever I click on a tab I should be able to show the corresponding menu and content. And the menu view and content view will have common background. How can I move this common background part into a common viewcontroller/class. And how can I maintain a common instance for all different views?

Please clarify me. If you have doubts in understanding please post it.

Thanks,
durai.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a viewcontroller which creates the basic background view. And wherever I want to show this common view, I will create a respective view controller which is subclasses the above basic view controller.

Thanks.